siunitx dollar per hour broken going from SI to qty
In my previous question, it was noted that \SI has been deprecated for at least a couple of years by now. Do start to use \qty instead of \SI.
I searched and replaced \SI with \qty as one does, but encountered the following:
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode = symbol,}
\begin{document}%
%\SI{5}[\$]{\per\hour}
\qty{5}[\$]{\per\hour}
\end{document}%

The line with SI still produces the desired $5/h output, but the line with qty produces an undefined control sequence error.
I've checked the latest siunitx pdf documentation and noted nothing under currency and searching for \$ is problematic.
How can the output $5/h be achieved using siunitx's \qty?

In v3, I tightened up the semantics here: the idea of support currencies was not the best plan. As such, you want
\$\qty{5}{\per\hour}

or similar.

"the idea of support currencies was not the best plan". I recently wrote a grant proposal and boy did I wish it had currency support with siunitx. Writing \texteuro\qty{32}{\per\mega\watt} felt so clunky. I really wish the backend could identify a list of known currencies (dollars, yen, euro, rupee, peso, etc.) and add that automatically in the front of the number. If I know how to work with base TeX, I would've helped, I swear!

@Miloop Some languages place currency signs in front of the value and some behind. So, such support would also need to be language-aware.

@JasperHabicht: I think I showed my ignorance on this matter. Thanks for letting me know.

makes sense to me, thank you

As Joseph said, the syntax is unsupported for \qty.
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  mode=text,
  per-mode = symbol,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\price}{O{}mm}{%
  \qty[input-digits=0123456789\$,#1]{\$#2}{#3}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\$}{}{\textdollar}

\begin{document}

\SI{5}[\$]{\per\hour}

\price{5}{\per\hour}

\textit{The charge is \price{5}{\per\hour}}

\end{document}


You can still do \price[<options>]{<number>}{<unit>}

Nice, also with the \price approach you have to change in just one place if the editor wants 5€/hour (the currency here in Spain, for example, is typeset as a unit, after the figures).
